# how to add list items in listview and this listview should display on dialog

Tags: android, listview, addition, listviewitem

code to retrive data from server

```
public void onPostExecute(String response) {
            //Log.i("r","response transactional details: "+ response);
            try {
                if (response.equals("NO_INTERNET")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (response.equals("ERROR")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else {
                     transactionDetailsList = new ArrayList<TransactionDetails>();

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        TransactionDetails transactionDetails1 = new TransactionDetails();
                        transactionDetails1.setCustomerNo(jsonObject.getString("CustomerNo"));
                        transactionDetails1.setAmount(jsonObject.getDouble("Amount"));
                        transactionDetails1.setStatus((byte) jsonObject.getInt("Status"));
                        transactionDetailsList.add(transactionDetails1);
                        Log.i("response",transactionDetailsList.toString());
                    }

                    LastTransactionsAdapter lastTransactionsAdapter = new LastTransactionsAdapter(getContext(),transactionDetailsList);
                    mainListView.setAdapter(lastTransactionsAdapter);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    LayoutInflater inflaterr = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View convertView = (View)inflaterr.inflate(R.layout.last_transaction_listview, null);
                    alertDialog.setView(convertView);
                    final AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                    alert.setTitle("Your last transactions");
                    alert.show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.fillInStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } finally {
//                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
```

LastTransactionsAdapter to retrieve data from POJO and set data on textviews 
also im trying to print getting text from textview but it not showing any value....pls suggest me changes to do in code

```
public class LastTransactionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
Context context;
final ArrayList<TransactionDetails> transactionDetailsList;

public LastTransactionsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TransactionDetails> t) {
    super(context,R.layout.last_transaction_textview,t);
    this.context = context;
    this.transactionDetailsList = t;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        TransactionDetails transactionDetail = (TransactionDetails)getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.last_transaction_textview, parent, false);

        TextView customerNo = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.customerTextView);
        TextView amount = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
        TextView status = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);

        customerNo.setText(transactionDetail.getCustomerNo().toString());
        amount.setText(transactionDetail.getAmount().toString());
        status.setText(transactionDetail.getStatus());
        Log.i("cust", customerNo.getText().toString());

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return transactionDetailsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return transactionDetailsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return transactionDetailsList.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: no sir, no any exception ........just showing something went wrong toast

Comment: So it means there is an error. Just debug and find where the problem is.